# How to insert data in API through a cron php

Tags: php, mysql, curl, cron

Hi i want to write code to insert data in MySQL table and along with it would also insert to API.

I am able to insert the data in MySQL database but when i write the code for push the data in API it will also not insert the data in MySQL table.

```
$fname = $value['first_name'].' '.$value['last_name'];
$phone = $value["phone_number"];
$email = $value["email"];
$city =  addslashes($value["city"]);
$client_source = "Home Visit";
$source = "Facebook Home Visit";
$z_uid=$value["z_uid"];

$query1="INSERT  INTO amplifon_web_leads(submitted,enquiry_id,yourname,email,phone,preferred_centre,status,region_id,brand_id,source,user_id,lead_handler_name,Priority,client_source) VALUES(date_add(now(),INTERVAL 630 Minute),CONCAT('AMP','$enquiry_code'),'$fname','$email','$phone','$city','16001','1601','16','$source','$user_id','$handler_name','','$client_source')";

mysqli_query($connection,$query1) or die ('Error updating database1');
$query2="DELETE FROM `amplifon_facebook_zipper` WHERE `z_uid`='$z_uid'";
mysqli_query($connection,$query2) or die ('Error updating database2');

$url = "http://APIURL.COM/Campaign/API/Intekill/Enquiry";
$enquiry_codes = CONCAT('AMP','$enquiry_code');
$data = array("Name" => $fname, "InterSkaleEnquiryLeadId" => $enquiry_codes,"Mobile"=>$phone,"Phone"=>$phone,"Email"=>$email,"CenterType"=>$city,"PrefCenter"=>$city, "Enquiry"=> "from cron", "OtherCenter"=> "null", "Pname"=>"null", "Pmobile"=>$phone, "CallDate"=> "null", "CallTime"=> "null","ClientSource"=> "null" );

$ch = curl_init( $url );
# Setup request to send json via POST.
$payload = json_encode( array( "Enquiry"=> $data ) );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
# Return response instead of printing.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
# Send request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I want to insert the data in API and MySQL Table.

Comment: what you mean by "also not insert"? does it get not inserted on api as well as well as db?

Comment: when i add api code it not inserted in db but when i remove api code it will inserted in db so i think i am doing something wrong in api code

Comment: but is it inserted on api? or do you get some error there?

Comment: Thanks @dharman but currently our primary goal is to push the data in API and db

Comment: @slepic No the data is not inserted in API also we don't get any error we also enable error reporting but no luck

Comment: You said that your data is not inserted to DB. It could be the problem that you are not using prepared statements. My comment was not off-topic. Please switch on MySQLi errors too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22662488/1839439

Comment: @dharman **Actually as i said when i remove API Code then the data is store in db but when i write the API code then both API and db not the get the data.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for the comments now it's work with following code there two mistake that i made.

1. I use concat() function that will generate error
2. I change content-type to encoded and it's works.

   ```
   $fname = $value['first_name'].' '.$value['last_name'];
   $phone = $value["phone_number"];
   $email = $value["email"];
   $city =  addslashes($value["city"]);
   $client_source = "Home Visit";
   $source = "Facebook Home Visit";
   $z_uid=$value["z_uid"];


   $query1="INSERT  INTO amplifon_web_leads(submitted,enquiry_id,yourname,email,phone,preferred_centre,status,region_id,brand_id,source,user_id,lead_handler_name,Priority,client_source) VALUES(date_add(now(),INTERVAL 630 Minute),CONCAT('AMP','$enquiry_code'),'$fname','$email','$phone','$city','16001','1601','16','$source','$user_id','$handler_name','','$client_source')";


   mysqli_query($connection,$query1) or die ('Error updating database1');
   $query2="DELETE FROM `amplifon_facebook_zipper` WHERE `z_uid`='$z_uid'";
   mysqli_query($connection,$query2) or die ('Error updating database2');


   $enquiry_codes = 'AMP'.'$enquiry_code';

   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://ipaddress/Campaign/API/InterSkill/Enquiry");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"Name=".$fname."&InterSkaleEnquiryLeadId=".$enquiry_codes."&Mobile=".$phone."&Phone=".$phone."&Email=".$email."&CenterType=".$city."&PrefCenter=".$city."&Enquiry=FROMcron&OtherCenter=null&Pname=null&Pmobile=null&CallDate=null&CallTime=null&ClientSource=null");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));


   // receive server response ...
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

   curl_close ($ch);
   ```